# Binomial Random Variables: $P(X=k)$ as $k$ goes from $0$ to $n$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

> If $X$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $p$, where $0 < p < 1$,
>   show that
>
> As $k$ goes from $0$ to $n$, $P(X = k)$ first increases and then decreases, reaching
>   its largest value when $k$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $(n + 1)p$.

The expression for $P(X=k+1)$ in terms of $P(X=k)$ is:

$P(X=k+1)=\frac{p}{1-p} \frac{n-k}{k+1}P(X=k), k=0,1,...,n-1$

where $P(X=k)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

How is this done?

Comment: You have a formula for $P(X=k+1)$ and $P(X=k)$. Try dividing them. Then show that $P(X=k+1)/P(X=k)$ is $\geq1$ up to some point, then $\leq 1$ after that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this factor:

$$P(X=k+1)=\underbrace {\frac{p}{1-p} \frac{n-k}{k+1}}_{\text{factor}} P(X=k)$$

Analyze it as $k$ varies.

Comment: Please don't analyze it as $k$ varies _continuously_. $k$ takes on integer values only, and nullUser's hint in the comments on the OP's question is by far the better approach.

Comment: Actually, you're right. That would be easier. Edited my answer.